# Is it possible to combine Sound objects in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

Is it possible to take two Sound objects and combine them into one Sound object so that one Sound plays, and then the second plays right after it? I can just play the first Sound and then the next right after it, but it would be much cleaner to combine them before playing the audio.

Comment: Cleaner? Unless you have some audible noise between sounds, there is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I don't believe it's natively supported by the Sound class. If you actually want to join them, I'm thinking you could put the data into two byte arrays and then join them.

But if I were you I would create a class that can hold multiple sounds. You can create some private methods which will play the sounds in order, and then public methods that can can start the sequence playing.